# Controlling a Stepper Motor with Android Things

Tags: android, android-things

I am totally new to stepper motors and i am struggling to control a stepper motor with Android Things. I have an Arduino program to control Nema 23 stepper motor that is connected to M542 driver. The below Arduino program works perfectly fine.

```
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(dirPin,LOW); // Enables the motor to move in a particular direction
  for(int x = 0; x < 1800; x++) {
    digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH); 
    delayMicroseconds(delayMS); 
    digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW); 
    delayMicroseconds(delayMS); 
  }
  digitalWrite(dirPin,HIGH); //Changes the rotations direction
  for(int x = 0; x < 1800; x++) {
    digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(delayMS);
    digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(delayMS);
  }
  //delay(1000);
}
```

Now i am trying to convert this program to Android Things and i am struggling here. I tried two different ways.
1) Just replacing the code with Android

```
private Runnable moveRailRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Exit if the GPIO is already closed
            if (dirPin == null || pulPin == null) {
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(moveRailRunnable);
                return;
            }
            try {
                int i = 0;
                while(i++<10000) {
                    pulPin.setValue(!pulPin.getValue());
                    mHandler.postDelayed(moveRailRunnable, 100);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error on PeripheralIO API", e);
            }
        }
    };
```

When running the above code, the motor is running very slow as there is a delay of milli seconds. But the arduino code has micro seconds.

2) Using A4988 module from https://github.com/Polidea/Polithings
Here also i have the same issue. If i perform the step one by one, i end up in the same problem that it moves very slow.

```
// Motor moves very slow with this code.
        A4988 sm = new A4988("BCM2","BCM3");
        sm.open();
        sm.setDirection(Direction.CLOCKWISE);
        sm.setResolution(A4988Resolution.FULL);
        sm.performStep(new StepDuration(50,0));
```

and when i use the rotate method, i couldnt get the motor to move at all.

```
// Motor doesnt move at all.
        A4988StepperMotor asm = new A4988StepperMotor(800,"BCM2", "BCM3");
        asm.rotate(360.0, Direction.COUNTERCLOCKWISE, A4988Resolution.FULL.getId(), 360);
        asm.close();
```

I really couldnt figure out how can i control the stepper motor that can move fast? Is that just a problem of delay? how can i give a microseconds delay then?

I thank you all in advance for helping me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stepper motors usually require high frequency signals. I didn't check that but I really doubt that AndroidOS is able to generate one of eg 10kHz and even period (maybe if you will use Android NDK... but still doubt it).

What I want to say is that android device is not meant to be a driver for stepper motor. It is meant to provide parameters for actual stepper motor driver. Why don't you build propper driver using Arduino and just communicate it with your Android App?

This is how the professional production solutions work. There is some sort of User Interface device (HMI pannel or PC) that sends user requests to driver layer.

Comment: Typically if Linux is used to generate step pulses, a realtime extension running at a level below the kernel does the actual work.  Or indeed, an external step-synchronizer is used, often interpreting something like g-code, for example in 3d printers and architecturally comparable desktop CNC machines.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I ended up using Rpi with Android Things as kind of server and it provides command to Arduino through USB Host api and Arduino does all operations of controlling the motor based on the command received from Rpi.

Answer (score 0):

As muminers mentioned, high frequency toggling is not something that is typically done directly with a Linux class device such as Android Things or a Raspberry Pi. The higher-level abstractions can result in inaccurate timing that is possible on microcontrollers.

However, in your case, you may be able to take advantage of [PWM](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/pwm.html) to send a higher frequency pulse without having to manually toggle GPIO continually.

Looking at the [I/O for a Raspberry Pi](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi-io.html), you'll need to connect to either `BCM18` or `BCM13` to use PWM.

After that, you can set the frequency and duty cycle. By adjusting the duty cycle, you can get more or less of the signal to your motor. Here's a code snippet:

```
pwm.setPwmFrequencyHz(120);
pwm.setPwmDutyCycle(25);

// Enable the PWM signal
pwm.setEnabled(true);
```

You can adjust the frequency to something more like 10KHz and see if that works better for you.

Answer (score 0):

first of all make a simple python script for handle stepper moter.
https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/controlling-stepper-motor-with-raspberry-pi
then install blueterm mobile app and pass the command.
to also change the some python script.

Comment: Links alone are not enough as answers. Links tend to die, and answers become useless. Please quote the parts of the page you linked that directly answer the question.

Comment: In addition to being little more than a link to a site with horrible popups, this method would only work for very slow stepping.